# how to remove the space form xml layout background.?

Tags: java, android

what ever blue color [image]line show is background image. name is  bluebackground. and it is  behind the gridview and bottomheader.

please tell how to remove this blue line space.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bluebackground" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
         android:src="@drawable/blackheader" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/etxsearch"
         android:layout_width="300dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:background="@drawable/searchtext"
         android:textSize="18dp" />

     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/gvMain"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/img_bottomheader"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
         android:background="#000000"
         android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
         android:numColumns="3"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         android:smoothScrollbar="true"
         android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img_bottomheader"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:src="@drawable/bottom" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

space is show behind the bluebackground.

Comment: You've set the gridview background as `android:background="#000000"` try setting it to transparent `android:background="##00FFFFFF"`

Comment: i want to remove blue line show in bottom..?? just see it show very small line

Comment: Ah right sorry, have you looked if removing `android:verticalSpacing="1dp"` is the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing: android:layout_marginTop="48dp"

Comment: see if setting android:layout_margin="0dp" for last ImageView and/or gridView works  set gridView android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Answer (score 1):

I have just re-arranged two of your Views - `GridView` and 'ImageView` (bottom) with minor changes. Check if the below code works:

```
  <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_bottomheader"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:src="@drawable/bottom" />

 <GridView
     android:id="@+id/gvMain"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_above="@id/img_bottomheader"
     android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
     android:background="#000000"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:numColumns="3"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"
     android:smoothScrollbar="true"
     android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
```

Comment: I have a doubt with the image you are using for your bottom-header `ImageView`. Can you recheck if it's completely black or has a blue line too?

Comment: Does my answer helped you or the image you were using for your bottom-header had a blue line?